# Adding a submenu as a menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently in the process of making the admin page for my clients a little bit less cluttered. I want them to be able to acces the Menus menu, but not the other Appearance submenus.
I could remove all the submenus from the Appearance menu, except the Menus menu, but that would be less than ideal.

So, is there a way to add a submenu button as a menu button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress: Change admin submenu order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766477/wordpress-change-admin-submenu-order)

Comment: Have you tried any code ?